# Calculate datediff between max date in one table and dates in another tables in weeks

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff, m

I am new to Power Bi and dax and I would like to calculate a datediff in weeks between the max date in one table and dates in another table.

[image]

I tried

```
DATEDIFF(TableA[Dates],MAX(TableB[Dates]),WEEK)
```

If I understand correctly then datediff only takes the difference between 2 dates and not a column.

Does anyone know how to do this? I would also be interested to know how this works with M-Language.

Comment: Try using a Measure: `=DATEDIFF( MIN( TableA[Dates] ), MAX( TableB[Dates] ), WEEK )`, which, when placed into a visual alongside the dates from TableA, should give you what you want. This assumes there is no active relationship between TableA and TableB.

Comment: Wouldn't that calculate the row wise datediff? I want to calculate one value against a column.

Comment: It would compare each of the entries in `TableA[Dates]` against the maximum value from `TableB[Dates]`. Which appears to be precisely what your initial statement asks for.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jos. The Code that I posted in my question actually worked. Don't know where I went wrong before. Your code produces a column with the same  value (max date -min date in weeks). The min was not what I was looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you're using a `Calculated Column` as opposed to my `Measure`?

Comment: Yes I was using calculate column. Why would a measure be different? I will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Yes, `Measures` and `Calculated Columns` have several important differences.

Answer (score 1):

The question of your problem is how DAX should know which two dates you compare. Suppose you want use matrix visual and you want to put TabA Date on its rows and TabB Date on its columns. Then you may create a measure for Values of that visual:

```
Measure = DATEDIFF( MAX( TableA[Date] ), MAX( TableB[Date]), WEEK )
```

Alternatively, you may construct a table in DAX that has both dates. Use CROSSJOIN and VALUES functions for that. And then add calculated column with the above measure.